# Brute force a hard drive when most of the password is known

Tags: passwords, brute-force, luks

I need to access a hard drive that is encrypted with LUKS. The password provided is incorrect, however it is only incorrect by a character or so.
The password itself is very strong and above 30 characters in length. How would one go about brute forcing their way into the hard drive with this information in mind to access the data or should the data loss simply be accepted?

Comment: This is quite a simple question: if only one character is wrong (assuming that it is only one charater) then the possible combinations are 26x30, which for password crackers is easy.  I am not familiar with LUKS, but it might be a case that if after X number of attempts the data is cleared. 

You can generate the password list very easily, using a simple Python script. I will knock something up and post it here if you like?

Comment: @KingJohnno - What you say is close to correct if there is only one character, but the OP says "a character or so". So if the password is only lowercase letters, is just 30 characters, and has 2 characters that are wrong, there are (25*30)*(25*29) possible replacements (25, not 26, because you wouldn't replace a letter with itself). But the OP says "above 30 characters in length" which makes me think that the OP only has an approximation of the correct password and that the situation is much more complex than it seems.

Answer (score 3):

[John the Ripper Jumbo](http://openwall.com/john/) has LUKS format available.  Use luks2john first, and then use JtR normally, walking through the characters one at a time to see which is wrong.